# Jquery how can I select only the .clicked DOM Element

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a list with buttons. All have the same class. How would I be able to select only the DOM element that was clicked using jQuery?

Say I wanted to call `.fadeOut()` on only the clicked button and leave the remaining buttons as they are...

**HTML:**

```
<ul>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" >click Me1!</button></li>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" >click Me2!</button></li>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" >click Me3!</button></li>
    <li><button class="sidebutton" >click Me4!</button></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: `this` would is clicked item.

Comment: Isn't this covered in **every** jQuery tutorial?

Comment: @Barmar but OP has searched all tutorials to no avail because this is *different*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("button").click(function(){
    $(this).fadeOut(); //this referes current clicked button
});
```

Answer (score 3):

try this:

```
$('.yourclass').click(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut(); //$(this) is the clicked button
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Two ways you could do this:

**1.** Assign an event handlers to each button:

```
$('.sidebutton').on('click', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

**2.** Assign one event handler to the `<ul>` and let the event propagate up:

```
$('ul').on('click', '.sidebutton', function () {
    $(this).fadeOut();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Pls try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Helper</title>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <ul>
        <li><button>Click me!</button></li>
        <li><button>Click me!</button></li>
        <li><button>Click me!</button></li>
        <li><button>Click me!</button></li>
    </ul>
</body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function(){
        $('li button').on('click', function(){
            $(this).fadeOut("slow", function(){
                console.log('Completed!');
            })
        })
    })();


</script>       
</html>
```